# "свернуть" вложенный массив в одномерный

Tags: массивы, php

есть N-мерный массив элементов с уникальными ключами **элементов-немассивов**.
Необходимо преобразовать его в одномерный.
Вопрос, возможно, элементарный, но подходящей функции из стандартных не вижу:
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php

Например, `array_merge_recursive()` сохраняет вложенную структуру исходного массива,
`array_map()` и некоторые другие требуют `callback` функцию, мне кажется это не красивое решение, т.к. все равно никаких преобразований над значениями элементов делать не надо.

Comment: тогда значит нужно написать свою рекурсивную функцию. Это достаточно просто. Схематический код

    f(a:array) {
      r:array = [];
      foreach x in a {
        if (x is array) {
           appendarray(r,f(x));
        } else {
           append(r,x)
        }
      }
      return r;
    }

`appendarray(a,b)` - добавляет массив `b` в конец `a`.

`append(a,b)` - добавляет значение `b` в конец `a`.

`(x is array)` - всевдоинструкция, проверяющая тип элемента, в php есть, нужно только найти имя.

Comment: Если бы не фигурные скобки я бы подумал что это какой-то псевдопитон =)
Пробовал...
<pre>
function x($array)
{
 foreach($array as $key=>$val)
 {
  if(is_array($val))
   $output[] = self::to_form_names($val);
  else $output[$key] = $val;
 }
 return $output;
}
</pre>
Не делает ничего, кроме как затирает ключи массивов =)

Comment: ошибка в строке `$output[$key] = x($val)`, Вы вставляете массив как один элемент. А нужно поэлементно добавить. В моем псевдокоде есть append и appendarray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чем вам не угодил `callback`?

```
$multiarray = ...;
$result = array();

array_walk_recursive($multiarray, function($value, $key) use (&$result){
    $result = array($key, $value); // тут возвращаете как вам хочется
});
```

Еще один интересный способ:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($multiarray));

$result = array();
foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
  $result[] = array($key, $value); // тут возвращаете как вам хочется
}
```